# window.showModalDialog - Browser annoyances

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, dom, showmodaldialog

Testing the showModalDialog method of the window element, I noticed that Firefox ignores the 'center' & 'resizable' options, although the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.showModalDialog) states that these options are supported.

Chrome is also ignoring the 'resizable' option, with only IE & Safari being the 'good' browsers.

Is there any tricks to make the others behave correctly?

Comment: Seems to be an old bug with Firefox : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=404668

Comment: More evidence with a solution to centering : http://cdmckay.org/blog/2009/07/07/how-to-kinda-fix-firefoxs-showmodaldialog/

Comment: I think that there is no standardized function called "showModalDialog" - http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/ You probably should use window.open instead. BTW. http://tjvantoll.com/2012/05/02/showmodaldialog-what-it-is-and-why-you-should-never-use-it/

Comment: Using window.open is the fallback I'm currently using. However, I need to have some modal window implementation. Only Chrome is not honoring this implementation, I'm still able to interact with the parent window.

Comment: Do you really need a new window? What about some new DOM element over the whole page?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, implementing OAuth and cannot browse away from current page. The annoyances aren't holding me back but I would like to solve it regardless.